# layout sizeHint qwidget

Tags: qt, qgridlayout

I am creating a widget which contains a chess table and six buttons which are displayed in 2 rows beneath the chess table. The button rows are wider than the chess table. Chess table and buttons are in a QGridLayout. Chess table has its own sizeHint calculated from the size of the squares.

After some operations I delete the buttons and resize the widget that contains everything to its sizeHint (`resize(sizeHint())`). The widget resizes properly in the vertical direction but in the horizontal direction it remains as wide as if the button rows were there. What is the problem ?

If I construct the widget only with the chess table the layout sizes the widget properly.

I am adding the code:

In the constructor of the window:

```
renderArea = new RenderArea(m_row,m_col,m_grid);

formLayout = new QGridLayout;

formLayout->addWidget(renderArea,0,0,1,3);

setLayout(formLayout);
```

In the function that adds the buttons:

```
addPlaneButton = new QPushButton(tr("Add plane"));
cancelButton = new QPushButton(tr("Cancel operation"));
movePlaneButton = new QPushButton(tr("Move plane"));
deletePlaneButton = new QPushButton(tr("Delete plane"));
rotatePlaneButton = new QPushButton(tr("Rotate plane"));
doneButton = new QPushButton(tr("Done"));
doneButton->setEnabled(false);

infoLabel = new QLabel(tr("Welcome to the plane editor"));
statusLabel = new QLabel();

formLayout->addWidget(statusLabel,1,0,1,3);
formLayout->addWidget(infoLabel,2,0,1,3);
formLayout->addWidget(addPlaneButton,3,0);
formLayout->addWidget(movePlaneButton,3,1);
formLayout->addWidget(deletePlaneButton,3,2);
formLayout->addWidget(rotatePlaneButton,4,0);
formLayout->addWidget(cancelButton,4,1);
formLayout->addWidget(doneButton, 4,2);
```

In the function that deletes everything besides the chess table:

```
formLayout->removeWidget(addPlaneButton);
formLayout->removeWidget(cancelButton);
formLayout->removeWidget(movePlaneButton);
formLayout->removeWidget(deletePlaneButton);
formLayout->removeWidget(rotatePlaneButton);
formLayout->removeWidget(doneButton);
formLayout->removeWidget(infoLabel);
formLayout->removeWidget(statusLabel);


delete addPlaneButton;
delete cancelButton;
delete movePlaneButton;
delete deletePlaneButton;
delete rotatePlaneButton;
delete doneButton;


delete infoLabel;
delete statusLabel;

resize(sizeHint());
```

The sizeHint for the chess table is calculated as:

```
return QSize(m_rowNo*spacing, m_colNo*spacing)+QSize(31,31);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must `activate()` the layout before for its `sizeHint()`, and subsequently the widget's `sizeHint()`, to be updated immediately after modifying the laid out widgets.
2. The calls to `layout->removeWidget()` are redundant. Simply `delete` the unneeded widgets. Qt handles all memory allocation in QWidget hierarchies. Deleting a QWidget without telling anyone on the Qt end of things is safe. There are sane exceptions of course: you can't delete a widget whose method is somewhere on the call stack, for example.
3. If you don't want to bother with calling `resize()`, you can set the appropriate size constraint on the widget's layout. For example:

   `layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);`

   This ensures that the widget will size itself only large enough to fit the contents per the `sizeHint()`.

Taking points 1 and 2 into account, the function that 'deletes everything besides the chess table' might look like the below:

```
void removeButtons() {
    delete addPlaneButton;
    delete cancelButton;
    delete movePlaneButton;
    delete deletePlaneButton;
    delete rotatePlaneButton;
    delete doneButton;
    delete infoLabel;
    delete statusLabel;

    formLayout->activate();
    resize(sizeHint());
}
```

Comment: According to `QLayout`'s documentation for `activate()`: "You should generally not need to call this because it is automatically called at the most appropriate times." I suggest to use `QWidget::updateGeometry()` to notify Qt about the layout changes.

Comment: Thank you Kuba Ober. I added the activate() function and resizing worked corectly. updateGeometry() does not do the job.

Comment: Johannes: `updateGeometry()` would be a redundant thing to call. It merely notifies the layout system that stuff has changed. There's no need to notify it, because deletion of laid out widgets does it already. I think the only good reason to call `updateGeometry()` is when you update `sizeHint()` or minimum/maximum sizes in a widget. A call to `activate()` forces the layout system to recalculate the layouts there and now. Normally it'd have been deferred to the event loop -- after the `resize(....)` call that then uses stale `sizeHint()` from old state of layouts. Qt docs are sometimes wrong.